# Query and order previous snapshots from Firestore Database

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch previous/older messages for a messaging app.  The first fetch is for a batch of latest messages.  But as users scrolls up, I'd like to get the previous messages and order them.

```
func getOlderMessages () {

    if self.lastSnapshot == nil {return}

    let next = Firestore.firestore().collection("chats/\(self.chat.id!)/messages")

        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: false)
        .limit(to: 10)
        .start(afterDocument: self.lastSnapshot)

    next.getDocuments(completion: { (snapShot, error) in

        for doc in snapShot!.documents {
            let message = Message(doc.data())
            self.chat.messages.insert(message, at: 0)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

        guard let last = snapShot?.documents.last else { return }

        self.lastSnapshot = last
    })
}
```

UPDATE:  Setting descending to TRUE seems to do the trick...

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would look up [query cursor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). Using a combination of `startAfter` and `limit` as shown in the doc. To trigger this load behaviour, you would also need to detect when the scrollTop == scrollHeight, this is when the page should trigger the previous messages query.